# TP link TL-WR1043ND can't access some homepages via wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I ran into some trouble with my wireless connection this morning. I can connect to my wireless network and it seems to be sending an receiving packets, but I can only access some websites like google.com and gmail.com, but pages like facebook.com do no work. Youtube works but I can't play any videos (pauses at start).

I am the only one using this network, I have 1 computer connected via wire and  2 computers on the wireless 1 pc and 1 mac, both have the same problem> I also installed DD-WRT with no complications and still does not work.

Thankful for any help that may result in me overcoming this :) 
(probably some noob mistake)

I have tried different browsers (chrome, IE, safari, mozilla)

Comment: Just to clarify. You have no problems if you connect the computers to the wire, and all have problems when you use wireless?

Comment: yes sir! seems so, im typing this from wired now

Comment: Sanity check: Are you connecting to the correct access point? (and not the neighbours AP with some filters installed).

Comment: yes ofc :) its my network and also my password so thats not it (i think)

Comment: for like 1 minute i got: DNS lookup failed. on all computers (including wired) and now suddenly all comps work :o

Comment: turned out ISP was the error

Comment: @nalydbob Thanks for sharing the result. Please add it as an answer or edit the question, so that other may see that this has been resolved.